# MySQL request to create candle sticks

Tags: python, mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a set of data from some assets, each trade with its time and date, reference ...
columns are Time, Ticker, Trade_id, Price, Quantity

I run the following MySQL request (within Python) to get the High and Low within the time frame I want:

```
SELECT MAX(`Time`),`Ticker`, MIN(`Price`), MAX(`Price`) 
FROM `{Tablename}` 
WHERE `Time` >={Start}  AND `Time` <={End}
```

I end up with part of my candle stick (High and Low) in a nice Tupple

```
(1679442679946, 'EUR', 0.07674, 0.0768)
```

But I also want the 1st price and last price within the time frame (Open and Close). Basically I am looking for something like:

Open :

```
Price WHERE `Time` = MIN(`Time`) AND `Time` >={Start}  AND `Time` <={End}
```

Close :

```
Price WHERE `Time` = MAX(`Time`) AND `Time` >={Start}  AND `Time` <={End}
```

... and end up with a nice tuple :

```
(1679442679946, 'EUR', 0.07678,0.0767,0.07674, 0.0768)
```

But I can't unless I run 3 different queries and end up with 3 tuples.

Is there a way to query it once and end up with the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: your query seems to be missing a group by clause on column ticker. So something like:

```
select max(time),ticker, min(price), max(price) 
from mytable
where time >= ? and time < ?
```

This is one case where window functions and  `distinct` may combine nicely:

```
select distinct ticker,
    min(time)  over(partition by ticker) min_time,
    max(time)  over(partition by ticker) max_time,
    min(price) over(partition by ticker) min_price,
    max(price) over(partition by ticker) max_price,
    first_value(price) over(partition by ticker order by time) first_price,
    first_value(price) over(partition by ticker order by time desc) last_price
from mytable t
where time >= ? and time < ?
```

Comment: Thank you GMB, but I have gone along the line of having one different table per ticker (for tome purposes) so I do not need to filter per the Ticker column... Which I guess makes this interesting method not suitable

Comment: @Mat: the method stays the same, you would just remove the `partition by` clauses.

Comment: Thanks again @GMB. I'm almost there but for the CLOSE PRICE:     


``` SELECT MAX(`Time`), MIN(`Price`), MAX(`Price`), FIRST_VALUE(`Price`) over(order by `Time`), LAST_VALUE(`Price`) over(order by `Time`)
FROM `{Tablename}`
WHERE `Time` >={Start} AND `Time` <={End};```


Works fine for LOW, HIGH and OPEN but it gives me the CLOsE = OPEN every time

example: (1679442687338, 0.07675, 0.0768, 0.07676, 0.07676) when the close should be 0.07678 in that particular example

I can't figure out the issue

Comment: @Mat: my query uses `first_value` to compute the closing price, not `last_value`.

Comment: I have tried FIRST_VALUE(`Price`) over(order by `Time` DESC) to get the closing price, but I get the same issue